# RSS.xml is only including some posts and not others in Drupal

Tags: drupal, rss

Is there a way to make all the posts promoted to font page to be included in RSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to make use of the Promote to Front Page / Sticky options under the Publishing options on the node.

Answer (score 0):

In the edit form for each content type defined in Drupal (in example, the one at http://example.com/admin/content/node-type/page), it is possible to promote to front page all the nodes of that content type.